# Want to click on a link, but open the page in the same tab, not open a new one in Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

In this particular test case, I want to click on the a tag, but I want the page to open up in the same tab, I don't want a new tab opening up.

I wrote the test case like this, but it is not working as a new tab opens up.  Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
cy.get("className").first().invoke("removeAttr", "href").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Tag element has `target=_blank` which is why a new tab is opened every time you are clicking it. The simple solution would be to replace the target value from `_blank` with `_self`.

```
cy.get("className").first().should($a => {
    $a.attr('target', '_self')
  }).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove `href` because that has the target address.

Check out [Cypress tips and tricks](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-target_blank)

> Figure out what you want to test. You can for example verify the link has the expected address and attribute target=_blank and call it a day.

```js
it('loads the about page', () => {
  cy.visit('index.html')
  cy.get('a').should($a => {
    expect($a.attr('href'), 'href').to.equal('/about.html')
    expect($a.attr('target'), 'target').to.equal('_blank')
  })
})
```

> We can also change the target attribute before clicking the link (but after confirming it to be blank). Then we can verify the second "tab" loads correctly.

```js
it('loads the about page', () => {
  cy.visit('index.html')
  cy.get('a').should($a => {
    expect($a.attr('href'), 'href').to.equal('/about.html')
    expect($a.attr('target'), 'target').to.equal('_blank')
    $a.attr('target', '_self')
  }).click()
  cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/about.html')
})
```

---

A slightly different approach is given by pavelsman [Clicking on Links That Open in New Tab](https://pavelsaman.github.io/clicking-on-links-that-open-in-new-tab-in-cypress.html)

**Blanking the target**

```js
cy.get('a')
  .invoke('attr', 'target', '')
  .click()
```

**Using cy.request() to follow the link**

```js
cy.get('a')
  .invoke('attr', 'href')
  .then(link => {
    cy.request(link)
      .then(res => expect(res.status).to.equal(200))
  });
```